# Not seen any thing on google map android app

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I don't see any thing on google map,lines type some is shown,
my first map view project is running successfully where only map is show and here when i add some more code as the tutorial goes on it is not working .. 
here is the

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
GoogleMap mMap;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final double SEATTLE_LAT = 47.60621,
        SEATTLE_LNG = -122.33207, SYDNEY_LAT = -33.867487,
        SYDNEY_LNG = 151.20699, NEWYORK_LAT = 40.714353,
        NEWYORK_LNG = -74.005973;

private static final float DEFAULTZOOM = 5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (servicesOK()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (initMap()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            gotoLocation(SEATTLE_LAT, SEATTLE_LNG, DEFAULTZOOM);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_xml_control);
           }
         }
    private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng,
        float zoom) {
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
    mMap.moveCamera(update);
    } 
    public boolean servicesOK() {
    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable,
                this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to Google play servieces",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean initMap() {
    if (mMap == null) {

        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment)  

     getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
        // gotoLocation(SEATTLE_LAT, SEATTLE_LNG);
        mMap = mapFrag.getMap();
    }
    return (mMap != null);
}

private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lag) {

    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lag);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll);
    mMap.moveCamera(update);
}
```

}

manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission a                                                                       
  ndroid:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />


  <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="my keyy" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you retrieved a gray map on your phone? If so, your `API_KEY` for your map did not set correctly.

Please try to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE) step by step, you will finally get a map on your phone.

For `MainAcitivity`, sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static LatLng goodLatLng = new LatLng(37, -120);
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private EditText et_address, et_finalAddress;
    LatLng addressPos, finalAddressPos;
    Marker addressMarker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et_address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressEditText);
        et_finalAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finalAddressEditText);


        // Initial Map
        try {

            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        // Put a dot on my current location
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        // 3D building
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        // Get zoom button
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(goodLatLng)
                .title("Hello"));
    }
```

For more details, please refer to my github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMapExample-android).